# Why do I get "disconnected framework"?

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, marathon

I have installed and configured Mesos and Marathon. Whenever I try to schedule an application, it remains in 'Waiting' state which seems to indicate that Marathon is waiting for offers from Mesos.

When I check the logs in Mesos, I see the following:

```
I0425 20:22:10.313910  4279 master.cpp:2231] Received SUBSCRIBE call for framework 'chronos-2.4.0' at scheduler-07d9654e-5c40-4172-a25d-97c565b5765d@127.0.1.1:50892
I0425 20:22:10.313987  4279 master.cpp:2302] Subscribing framework chronos-2.4.0 with checkpointing enabled and capabilities [  ]
I0425 20:22:10.313994  4279 master.cpp:2312] Framework c16a5bfb-838e-4d43-bf3c-21bf94358ab5-0001 (chronos-2.4.0) at scheduler-07d9654e-5c40-4172-a25d-97c565b5765d@127.0.1.1:50892 already subscribed, resending acknowledgement
W0425 20:22:10.314007  4279 master.hpp:1764] Master attempted to send message to disconnected framework c16a5bfb-838e-4d43-bf3c-21bf94358ab5-0001 (chronos-2.4.0) at scheduler-07d9654e-5c40-4172-a25d-97c565b5765d@127.0.1.1:50892
E0425 20:22:10.314193  4287 process.cpp:1958] Failed to shutdown socket with fd 39: Transport endpoint is not connected
I0425 20:22:11.226884  4284 master.cpp:2231] Received SUBSCRIBE call for framework 'marathon' at scheduler-d998dfb4-9cc2-4d22-9cb7-416433c2fb57@127.0.1.1:35928
I0425 20:22:11.226959  4284 master.cpp:2302] Subscribing framework marathon with checkpointing enabled and capabilities [  ]
I0425 20:22:11.226969  4284 master.cpp:2312] Framework c16a5bfb-838e-4d43-bf3c-21bf94358ab5-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-d998dfb4-9cc2-4d22-9cb7-416433c2fb57@127.0.1.1:35928 already subscribed, resending acknowledgement
W0425 20:22:11.226982  4284 master.hpp:1764] Master attempted to send message to disconnected framework c16a5bfb-838e-4d43-bf3c-21bf94358ab5-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-d998dfb4-9cc2-4d22-9cb7-416433c2fb57@127.0.1.1:35928
E0425 20:22:11.227226  4287 process.cpp:1958] Failed to shutdown socket with fd 39: Transport endpoint is not connected
I0425 20:22:12.113598  4281 http.cpp:312] HTTP GET for /master/state from 192.0.2.1:49698 with User-Agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.112 Safari/537.36'
I0425 20:22:12.314221  4286 master.cpp:2231] Received SUBSCRIBE call for framework 'chronos-2.4.0' at scheduler-07d9654e-5c40-4172-a25d-97c565b5765d@127.0.1.1:50892
I0425 20:22:12.314304  4286 master.cpp:2302] Subscribing framework chronos-2.4.0 with checkpointing enabled and capabilities [  ]
I0425 20:22:12.314312  4286 master.cpp:2312] Framework c16a5bfb-838e-4d43-bf3c-21bf94358ab5-0001 (chronos-2.4.0) at scheduler-07d9654e-5c40-4172-a25d-97c565b5765d@127.0.1.1:50892 already subscribed, resending acknowledgement
W0425 20:22:12.314337  4286 master.hpp:1764] Master attempted to send message to disconnected framework c16a5bfb-838e-4d43-bf3c-21bf94358ab5-0001 (chronos-2.4.0) at scheduler-07d9654e-5c40-4172-a25d-97c565b5765d@127.0.1.1:50892
E0425 20:22:12.314524  4287 process.cpp:1958] Failed to shutdown socket with fd 39: Transport endpoint is not connected
I0425 20:22:13.081887  4284 master.cpp:2231] Received SUBSCRIBE call for framework 'marathon' at scheduler-d998dfb4-9cc2-4d22-9cb7-416433c2fb57@127.0.1.1:35928
I0425 20:22:13.081964  4284 master.cpp:2302] Subscribing framework marathon with checkpointing enabled and capabilities [  ]
I0425 20:22:13.081987  4284 master.cpp:2312] Framework c16a5bfb-838e-4d43-bf3c-21bf94358ab5-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-d998dfb4-9cc2-4d22-9cb7-416433c2fb57@127.0.1.1:35928 already subscribed, resending acknowledgement
W0425 20:22:13.082005  4284 master.hpp:1764] Master attempted to send message to disconnected framework c16a5bfb-838e-4d43-bf3c-21bf94358ab5-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-d998dfb4-9cc2-4d22-9cb7-416433c2fb57@127.0.1.1:35928
E0425 20:22:13.082314  4287 process.cpp:1958] Failed to shutdown socket with fd 39: Transport endpoint is not connected
I0425 20:22:13.221590  4282 master.cpp:2231] Received SUBSCRIBE call for framework 'marathon' at scheduler-d998dfb4-9cc2-4d22-9cb7-416433c2fb57@127.0.1.1:35928
I0425 20:22:13.221664  4282 master.cpp:2302] Subscribing framework marathon with checkpointing enabled and capabilities [  ]
I0425 20:22:13.221674  4282 master.cpp:2312] Framework c16a5bfb-838e-4d43-bf3c-21bf94358ab5-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-d998dfb4-9cc2-4d22-9cb7-416433c2fb57@127.0.1.1:35928 already subscribed, resending acknowledgement
W0425 20:22:13.221688  4282 master.hpp:1764] Master attempted to send message to disconnected framework c16a5bfb-838e-4d43-bf3c-21bf94358ab5-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-d998dfb4-9cc2-4d22-9cb7-416433c2fb57@127.0.1.1:35928
E0425 20:22:13.222162  4287 process.cpp:1958] Failed to shutdown socket with fd 39: Transport endpoint is not connected
I0425 20:22:14.412215  4286 master.cpp:2231] Received SUBSCRIBE call for framework 'marathon' at scheduler-d998dfb4-9cc2-4d22-9cb7-416433c2fb57@127.0.1.1:35928
I0425 20:22:14.412281  4286 master.cpp:2302] Subscribing framework marathon with checkpointing enabled and capabilities [  ]
I0425 20:22:14.412289  4286 master.cpp:2312] Framework c16a5bfb-838e-4d43-bf3c-21bf94358ab5-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-d998dfb4-9cc2-4d22-9cb7-416433c2fb57@127.0.1.1:35928 already subscribed, resending acknowledgement
W0425 20:22:14.412302  4286 master.hpp:1764] Master attempted to send message to disconnected framework c16a5bfb-838e-4d43-bf3c-21bf94358ab5-0000 (marathon) at scheduler-d998dfb4-9cc2-4d22-9cb7-416433c2fb57@127.0.1.1:35928
E0425 20:22:14.412495  4287 process.cpp:1958] Failed to shutdown socket with fd 39: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

Any idea as to why it mentions a 'disconnected' framework. In Mesos, I can see the 3 slaves and the Marathon (and Chronos) framework are mentioned in the 'active frameworks'.

The /etc/hosts mention the following entries:

```
192.0.2.11  master1  # VAGRANT: cd38e81ab8742b23dfbcb913468368ea (master1) / 1b611425-dbad-4bd0-8727-4169c09ec045
192.0.2.51  slave1  # VAGRANT: 94630539b67d178dddffda29a0313a75 (slave1) / 1a1694de-2bd2-4d96-bdf2-dd6767d1f310
192.0.2.52  slave2  # VAGRANT: 306e67b33b327b3d1c9990bf1316a321 (slave2) / bdbd677e-5298-4d49-90a8-e521139dd127
192.0.2.12  master2  # VAGRANT: fb338e9e9c001a5bfab605387ba88d02 (master2) / bdccfd80-b1e6-48a0-8986-b24c7cbd7a25
192.0.2.53  slave3  # VAGRANT: 3913b3358eadc90c622859ddb90bfede (slave3) / 786cbe69-2af5-43b7-8e70-d6cc07d4ddf4
192.0.2.13  master3  # VAGRANT: 92cdd6e36a6c0391e2a66f73661e56fe (master3) / 03bb2c16-f474-4412-b8f4-fce82e12955c
```

Note: in case more info is needed on how the cluster was installed, please refer to [this](http://www.wapptastic.com/mesos-marathon-installation-using-vagrant/)

Answer (score 2):

You can also set `LIBPROCESS_IP` as environment variable. I think this is better than changing the `/etc/hosts`.

Found the solution here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/marathon-framework/1qboeZTOLU4

Comment: You can set this environment variable in a config file used by the service. For example in Ubuntu, in /etc/default/marathon

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to make sure that the hostnames are resolvable to actual IP addresses.

That's at least what fixed my problems when Marathon etc. tried to bind to `127.0.1.1` on Ubuntu. I.e. you should add on each host the IP to hostname mappings, e.g.

```
192.0.2.11 master1
```

entry in the `/etc/hosts` file either before the mapping of the `127.0.1.1` to the hostname, or remove the `127.0.1.1` entry entirely. The Vagrant plugin [vagrant-hostsupdater](https://github.com/cogitatio/vagrant-hostsupdater) might help.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried indeed the vagrant-hostsupdater but it doesn't solve it. Situation remains that the application in Marathon remains in 'waiting' state.

Comment: Have you checked the contents of the `/etc/hosts` on each host and verified that they contain an actual private ip? If so, have you restarted the mesos master/slave/marathon services? Can you show the contents?

Comment: I updated the original question to add the /etc/hosts content. But all the entries are there.

Comment: Ok, but is the `127.0.1.1` entry still there? And have you restarted the services? If so, what's in the logs?